# Removing Duplicates Between 2 Columns VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on pulling some data from a site, placing it in column J comparing it to another column of data in column K and then removing any duplicates found between the two columns in column J.

Right now I am using this but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas for how to get this working properly?

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()

'Create Range for SAP Batches
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range


'Finds last cell in column J
    Set rng2 = .Range("K2").End(xlDown)

ActiveSheet.Range("J2:rng2").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2),   Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: can you be more specific as to what is not working?  Are you getting error, wrong output,...?

Comment: It is actually not giving any error message. I tried inputting this     ActiveSheet.Range("J2:K70").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 11), Header:=xlNoinstead to force it to use a specific range just to make sure it wasn't seeing rng2 as something strange and it gives me error 1004 (application/ Object defined error)

Comment: `Range("J2:rng2")` doesn't make sense, the rng2 should be outside the quotes `Range("J2:" & rng2")"`.

Comment: Made a bit of a dog's dinner of that. You could just use `Range("J2",range("J" & rows.count).end(xlup))).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2),   Header:=xlNo`

Comment: Sorry but using that gave me "Invalid argument or procedure "

Comment: Hm, I think the second J should be a K.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("J2",rng2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2),   Header:=xlNo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the `FIND()` method, deleting from the bottom moving upwards:

```
Sub KillDuplicated()
    Dim J As Range, K As Range
    Dim rc As Long
    rc = Rows.Count
    Set J = Range("J1:J" & Cells(rc, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set K = Range("K1:K" & Cells(rc, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
    jcnt = J.Count

    For i = jcnt To 1 Step -1
        If K.Find(what:=Cells(i, "J"), after:=K(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            Cells(i, "J").Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]